# Why this code works? Task with adding static keyword

Tags: java, static

Can anyone tell me why this works? Task was to add minimum static keywords to make this code works. Static with method1 and method2 I can understand but why add it to int step?

```
/* Minimum number of static keywords
Add the minimum number of static keywords to make the code compile and the program to successfully complete.
*/

public class Solution {
    public static int step; //static was added here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method1();
    }

    public static void method1() {  //static was added here
        method2();
    }


    public static void method2() {  //static was added here
        new Solution().method3();
    }

    public void method3() {
        method4();
    }

    public void method4() {
        step++;
        for (StackTraceElement element : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())
            System.out.println(element);
        if (step > 1) return;
        main(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow what a horrible code example. Who inflicted this on you?

Comment: It's not needed to *compile*, but it's needed to make it terminate... but as T.J. Crowder said, this is utterly horrible.

Comment: horrible why? it's just some task from java training course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if `step` isn't static, it'll be specific to the object created in `method2`, and will always start out at 0 and become 1 after having been incremented by `method4`, and `1 > 1` is false, so we wouldn't return before calling `main` again. So the program would endlessly recurse (well, endless until it overflows the stack).